# How can I copy my keybindings from one character to another?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I just created my 2nd Star Wars: The Old republic character, and I see that new characters are set to the default keybindings. I'd changed quite a few on my first character and don't want to have to manually reset them all.

Is there a way to copy over the keybindings from one character to another, either in the game or by copying/renaming files on my hard drive?

Comment: One of the features I enjoyed from RIFT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was added with Patch 4.0.  Open Preferences and go to the Keybinding Import/Export tab on the bottom right.  In the text box at the bottom left you can type a name and hit the Save (floppy disk icon) button, and then go to your other character and hit the Load (page icon) beside that name in the Key Presets list.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 10):

Key bindings seem to be stored on the server, so there is currently no way to copy them from one character to another.  The INI files for each character only control chat colors and which custom channels you join (as well as a few other UI settings).

INI files are under: 
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\SWTOR\swtor\settings

Bioware has mentioned that they're looking at ways to export/import key bindings, or copy them between characters, but there are no firm plans yet.

Comment: If you know where they said it, it would be nice to include the link.

Comment: Just a heads up to anyone looking: nope, hasn't happened in over three years, so it's pretty much certain it won't happen, ever.

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard Check out my answer.

Comment: @MatthewRead Yup, I was quite happy being proven wrong with 4.0.  :D